# Tkinter- UI objects to be serialized and saved in a new file

Tags: python, tkinter

I want my entries to be saved in a file

```
filename= filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode="wb",defaultextension=".txt")
with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    dill.dump(data,f)
```

This code gives an error. Is there any other way of doing it.

```
TypeError: invalid file: <_io.BufferedWriter name='C:/Users/random.txt'>
```

Comment: I have edited my question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filedialog.asksaveasfile` [returns an opened file](http://web.archive.org/web/20160226040047_id/http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog). Hence you are getting an error when you are trying open it again. Just try to use it as it was opened before.

```
file= filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode="wb",defaultextension=".txt")
if file is not None: # returns `None` if cancel's out
    dill.dump(data,file)
```